# Using T from Option<T> as function parameter in Rust

Tags: rust

For this code:

```
fn inner_compare<T:PartialEq+PartialOrd>(&self, val: T, fixed_val: T) -> bool {
    match self.operator {
        "==" => val == fixed_val,
        ">=" => val >= fixed_val,
        "<=" => val <= fixed_val,
        ">" => val > fixed_val,
        "<" => val < fixed_val,
        _ => false,
    }
}
```

Calling

```
self.inner_compare(val, self.fixed_int_val);
```

Where `self` is the of the same type in both code snippets, and `self.fixed_int_val` is an `Option<int>`, how do I use only the `int` in the function parameter?  The current call errors with

```
main.rs:29:52: 29:70 error: mismatched types: expected `T` but found `core::option::Option<int>` (expected type parameter but found enum core::option::Option)
```

May be a stupid question, but I haven't found much documentation on how to cast an option back to its original type after calling `Some()`.

Comment: Is it intended that you would pass `T` by value here ? Some types are expensive to clone (`BigInt` comes to mind), so passing by reference might be better.

Comment: The T here could be an int or a &str, so the data shouldn't be expensive to clone.  Good to note, though, as I will probably run into this later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of extracting the original value from an Option.  Since an Option is an enum it can represent two variants, None or Some(x).  Using pattern matching you can handle both.

```
match self.fixed_int_val {
    Some(x) => self.inner_compare(val, x), //x in this case is the int contained in self.fixed_int_val
    None => ,//include logic for whatever your failure state is here
}
```

There is the other option of using the unwrap or expect methods.  Use unwrap if you're 100% sure that you'll be handling a Some(x) variant or you want the result to fail in the event of None.  Unwrap moves the value out of Some(x).

```
self.inner_compare(val, self.fixed_int_val.unwrap());
```

There is also the expect method for including a custom fail message.

```
self.inner_compare(val, self.fixed_int_val
                            .expect("Encountered None in self.fixed_int_val"));
```

You can find various methods relating to the Option type [here](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/option/type.Option.html)